# Weka J48 Gets stuck on Building Model on Training Data

Tags: csv, machine-learning, weka, j48

I'm trying to use Weka to look at my data sets.  When I load my data set in, and I got to classify and I choose J48 and click start it will being normally, my bird in the bottom right hand corner will go back and forth and there will be a x 1 next to it.  The status will update to "Building model on train data" but then after a second or two the bird will stop and sit back down, and it will change to x 0.  No further progress is made after that.

The file I am looking at is a csv file with 5 columns.  The first row, is a row of labels, and the total amount of rows are 1971 (in each column obviously).

I have done some research on this and found no solutions.  Possibly I'm looking in the wrong place?  Any guidance or resolutions to this issue would be much appreciated!

[Img of Screen when stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTDeg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May have found a solution myself... It could of been due to the size of the data.  I reduced the data amount and it started loading what looks like large matrix's.  I'll provide two screenshots.  Does this seem like a safe assumption to make?  It was due to data size?  Confirmation would be appreciated.

[Screenshot of J48 Results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRPbf.png)

[Screenshot of J48 Results 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzOMF.png)

Comment: I've notice through several tests that it sometimes still gets stuck with the original error but most of the time is running like the solution posted.